# How to force value of progress bar to 100

Tags: javascript

I am following [this tutorial on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp) about how to implement a simple progress bar

I want the progress bar to finish by force the value to 100 or some other way.

```
function move(w) {
          var width = parseInt(w);
          var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
          var id = setInterval(frame, 300);
          function frame() {
            if (width >= 100) {
              clearInterval(id);
            } else {
              width+=1; 
              elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
              elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
            }
          }
        }
```

Call function

```
 move(10);
```

Now I want it to finish I call it again

```
move(100);
```

the above isn't working though, why?

Comment: What progress bar are you using?

Comment: Please ***read*** the code, the thing preventing you is ***clearly*** there in the ***conditional statement***.

Comment: That's a pretty rubbish progress bar. It's the progress of nothing, it's just a bar that moves gradually to 100. I'd find yourself a better tutorial

Comment: @Liam the point of the progress is most likely to teach you about the element itself, so you can in the future implement it to a specific need.

Comment: That isn't really made clear in the tutorial though is it. It's typical w3schools rubbish. IMO don't bother with this site. It's notoriously inaccurate.

Comment: @Liam I think it is made infinitely clear if you read the steps. Unless of course this is just a good 'ole W3Schools bash.

Comment: what part of *Learn how to create a progress bar using JavaScript.* explains what this actually is, which is simply a bar that fills over a period of time. Like I said, this is the progress of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function `move(100)` is not working just because of there is no logic for it.

You have to add this. See below code:

```
function move(w) {
  var width = parseInt(w);
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var id = setInterval(frame, 300);
  function frame() {
    if (width > 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else if(width == 100) {
      elem.style.width = width + '%';  //add this line
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; //add this line
    } else {
      width+=1; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you do this then calling `move(10);move(20);` will result in two increments. Every time you call move without specifying 100 it'll add a new increment. The method is designed to be called once and once only.

Comment: It would best to explain what is done seeing as the OP was struggling with a simple conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="move(54)">Click Me</button> 

<script>
function move(len) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= len) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

passing an argument and accepting it solves this